# Send hyperlinks in email as links extracted from excel cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell which asks for location of documents. I want to send an email with that document location as a `clickable link` by specifying the `href` as the document location.

I extracted document location from the cell :

```
document_location = Range("F22").Value
```

I got the document_location as string.

Now, the thing is that I want to send an email and the Email body should consist of a link with the document_location as `href`.

I tried this :

```
olMail.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:10pt;font-family:Verdana>" & "<a href=" & document_location & ">" & document_location_as_clickable_link & "</a>" & "</BODY>"
```

But this shows the `document_location_as_clickable_link` as text, not reading the `href` statement.

I also tried this :

```
olMail.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:10pt;font-family:Verdana>" & "<a href=document_location>" & document_location_as_clickable_link & "</a>" & "</BODY>"
```

this converts the `document_location_as_clickable_link` into a hyperlink, but the `href` part is taken as "document_location", not the value which is extracted from cell. By saying this I meant, when i click `document_location_as_clickable_link`, it opens in a new tab, but the address turns out to be : `http://document_location/` , which is not the value extracted from the cell.

Please help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub MailLink()
With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
    .To = Cells(1, 1)
    .CC = Cells(2, 1)
    .Subject = "Test"
    .HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:10pt;font-family:Verdana>" & "<a href=""" & Range("F22") & """ >" & Range("F22") & " </a>" & "</BODY>"
    .display
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Sorry, that is not working. document_location_as_clickable_link is a text that appears in the email body. When I "Debug.Print document_location_as_clickable_link" , in the immediate browser it shows the link which is in Range("F22"). The output in immediate browser is : document_location_as_clickable_link <link>

Comment: I assumed you wanted a name ("document location as clickable link")  I'll edit my answer